# Connection has timed out when trying to access spring boot app from another machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot app which will be usable in a LAN. I'm running the command `mvn spring-boot:run`, the application is launched perfectly, i can access it via localhost but not via other machines : The page loads until the error : `The connection has timed out` appears .
ANy recommendations ?

Comment: What does the person responsible for the LAN say might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not accessible because the port in which your application is running is not exposed to the other machines. You can open firewall port to access it across the network.

The best approach is to setup either `Apache httpd` or `nginx` as fron't server to server your application on regular ports(80 and 443).